# Reference application storage in HTML assets

Tags: android

My Android app uses HTML files included as assets and displays these inside WebViews.
The HTML files must reference other files created dynamically by my application. The dynamic content cannot be included statically in /assets nor should it be fetched online every time the HTML is loaded inside the WebView. Instead, the app must fetch/generate the online content once and store it for future reference when an HTML file is displayed.

I have found two solutions up to now, and neither is satisfactory:

1. Place all content inside /assets statically. Then I can reference it inside the HTML files as follows:

   TAG src="image.gif" END_TAG
2. Store the dynamic content in the sdcard and reference it from HTML as follows:

   TAG src="/sdcard/app/image.gif" END_TAG

The first solution does not allow for dynamic content as (I think that) I cannot write to /assets dynamically. The second solution works but it is not great. First, I hard-encode references to /sdcard which I do not feel comfortable with. Second, the device has to have an SD card installed and mounted.

Overall, I would prefer the be able to store the dynamic content inside the app's on-device memory and then reference it from HTML. Is this reasonable/good-practice/possible?

Note that the "dynamic content" is not so dynamic --- it is updated very rarely and I want to have it cached.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use your app's cache storage? See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

Comment: Link is messed up, but go to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html and look at getCacheDir()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first solution does not allow for dynamic content as (I think that) I cannot write to /assets dynamically.

Correct.

> Overall, I would prefer the be able to store the dynamic content inside the app's on-device memory and then reference it from HTML. Is this reasonable/good-practice/possible?

Possible? Yes. Create a `ContentProvider` to serve your content, then use `content://` URLs, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I wasted quite a lot on time of this. Apparently, content providers are mainly targeted to structured data. I had to find my way about how to serve files though the content provider to make it work. The main trick is to override the `openFile` method of the `ContentProvider` class. For completeness, here is the relevant code from my final content provider used to serve a single file to WebViews.

```
public class MapContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    String FILENAME="afile";
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "my.package.name.provider";
    public static final String IMAGE = "imgname";

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        try {
            byte[] ba=values.getAsByteArray("afile");
            Context context=getContext();
            context.deleteFile(FILENAME);
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(ba, 0, ba.length);
            fos.close();
            return Uri.parse(AUTHORITY+"/"+IMAGE);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("MapController",e);
        }
        return Uri.parse("");

    }

    @Override
    public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File root = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),FILENAME);
        return ParcelFileDescriptor.open(root, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    }

//All the other overriden methods are ommited as they are typically never invoked in my dead-simple implementation

}
```

For more information (dear google user) about how to use `ContentProvider`s, do read the documentation. They have done a decent job explaining their purpose.